# YAML Header Shiny Slider Range Input

Tags: r, shiny, yaml, r-markdown

I am wanting to get a numerical range for my knitted r-markdown pdf file.  I have parameters set up such as:

```
params:
  file:
    input: file
    label: "File:"
    value: "U:/Folder/file"
  Start_Date: 
    label: "Date of Report"
    input: date
    value: "2018-12-31"
```

and I want to add a slider input, as a range.

following what I've seen when other users did this in their regular code area, (NOTO YAML headers) I've modified it to get:

```
Number_Range: 
    input: slider
    label: "Range:"
    min: 6
    max: 12
    value: c(8,9)
```

I've also tried with `value:` ``` &``r c(8,10)``& ``` but I get the error described below. (with only one ` and no &, I just can't get it to show up right on this forum) When I do my first example, I am able to see my slider input, but It does not allow me to choose 2 numbers for a range.

```
Warning: Error in getSliderType: argument "min" is missing, with no default
  57: dropNulls
  56: getSliderType
  55: <Anonymous>
  53: param.ui
  52: FUN
  51: lapply
  50: server
Error in getSliderType(min, max, value) : 
  argument "min" is missing, with no default
```

This above is something I've gotten before I added a max and a min.  But since I've added it, I can see the slider, but I thought it might have info relevant to my question.

```
Error in yaml::yaml.load(yaml, handlers = knit_params_handlers(evaluate = evaluate),  : 
  Scanner error: while scanning for the next token at line 37, column 12 found character that cannot start any token at line 37, column 12
```

Answer (score 1):

After 3 hours of banging my head against the wall, my search brought me to this website: 
https://www.kdnuggets.com/2019/06/ten-useful-things-r.html

And while #7 is only to show you how to get the knit with parameters Userform pop up in the first place, it answered my question by showing `value: [8,9]` as a replacement for the in chunk text `value: c(8,9)`.